# Increase maximum product price in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, product-prices

I'm using magento verison 2.1.4, when i tried to set the product price more than **100,000,000.00** it always set to **100,000,000.00** , is there a way to increase maximum product price?

Comment: @Moose Please check  question properly, It  related with Magento 2.0